# Having files opening in tabs in GVim

Tags: tabs, gvim, gvimrc

I'm having trouble with `gvim` and tabs. Using Ubuntu, there is the `gedit` editor, which opens files in new tabs, but `gvim` opens a new window for each file i open. I definitely prefer to have tabs, just like every other application I use. Having 5 gvim windows open simultenously overwhelms me.

So, is there any way to edit .gvimrc to make it open new files in new tabs instead of opening a new gvim window? I definitely prefer a .gvimrc solution over a Nautilus solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the client/server feature of vim/gvim.

```
gvim --remote-tab myfile
```

This works for both terminal and GUI versions of vim, as long as they are compiled (`vim --version`) with the **`+clientserver`** feature. (Optionally add `--servername foo` to set the instance name, which defaults to `GVIM`.)

Unfortunately, you cannot do this from `.vimrc`. You will have to, either:

- write a **wrapper script**, for example, **`~/bin/gvim`**:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec /usr/bin/gvim --remote-tab-silent "$@"
  ```

  (`--remote-tab-silent` will cause a new server to be silently started if needed)
- modify the **gvim.desktop** file to include the server commands:

  ```
  $ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
  $ cp {/usr,~/.local}/share/applications/gvim.desktop
  $ vim -e ~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop
  :/^Exec=/ s/gvim/& --remote-tab-silent/
  :wq
  $
  ```

The wrapper script method will probably cover more cases than editing the .desktop file.

Comment: Thanks! I used the wrapper script method and it works perfectly! Using a wrapper script is more portable, as I can clone my dotfiles anywhere and tabbed gvim will then just work.

Comment: For anyone having problems with the `gvim.desktop` method, try using this exec line: `Exec=bash -c "gvim --remote-tab-silent %f || gvim"`. This makes the dash icon still work. Also, if you're getting a spinning cursor for a long time after opening gvim, set `StartupNotify` to `true`.